# Count the total number of integers between 1 and 999 having distinct digits and are even

Tags: combinatorics

My approach:
I split this problem into cases.
**Case 1:** For single digit integer (4 integers)
**Case 2:** For double digit integers
For digit at one's place, we can have (0,2,4,6,8)
Now at ten's place, we can have 8 possibilities ( except 0 and the digit we choose at one's place). Hence, it will be $8 * 5 = 40$.
Now, the problem is that i counted them manually, and i found that there are 41 such numbers instead of 40.
**Case 3:** For three digit integers
I did not proceed as i believe i'll be making similar mistake here also.
Where am i making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative response.

Since other responses have diagnosed the OP's (i.e. original poster's) work, I can show a shortcut.

For this particular problem, I like the OP's case separation.

- For $~1 \leq n \leq 9~$ : $(4)$ numbers.
- For $~10 \leq n \leq 99~$ : 
  Ignoring that zero-filling is outlawed, you have 
  $5 \times 9 = 45,~$ since there are $5$ choices for the rightmost digit. 
  From this you must deduct the even numbers that have zero in the leftmost (zero-filled) digit.
  There are $(4)$ such numbers. 
  Therefore, the computation here is $(5 \times 9) - 4 = (41) ~$ numbers.
- A similar shortcut is employed for $3$ digit numbers. 
  You start with the computation of 
  $5 \times 9 \times 8 = 360.$ 
  From this you deduct $4 \times 8$ which represents 
  the number of ways of satisfying the constraint with a $0$ in the leftmost digit. 
  Therefore, the computation here is $360 - 32 = (328) ~$ numbers.

Putting it all together, you have

$$4 + 41 + 328 = 373 ~\text{numbers}.$$

Comment: I found it extremely insightful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here:

> we can have 8 possibilities ( except 0 and the digit we choose at one's place)

What if the digit you chose at the one's place was $0$? Then there are 9 possibilities for the ten's place.

Comment: sir, so should i make this also a separate case? Like the one's that end with 0 and one that end with 2,4,6,8 ? I am getting 41 this way. And i believe this will work for case 3 as well. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @taurus05: it gets a bit more complicated with more digits. You have three cases, not just two: (i) final digit is zero; (ii) some other digit is zero; (iii) all digits are non-zero.

Comment: I'm getting following result with 2 cases for 3 digit integer. In first case, i placed 0 at ones place and total possibilities are (9*8), In second case, when any of (2,4,6,8) is present at one's place, then total possibilities are (8*8 *4) as 0 can occur at one's place. Is this wrong?

Comment: I don't know. I've told you how I would do it.

Comment: Going by your approach, there will be some overlapping values for case 2 and case 3. Isn't it?

Comment: @taurus05  You have correctly handled the two-digit and three-digit cases in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another point of view into the question, by using a programmatic (and brute force) approach, I came up with this JavaScript 2016 snippet:

```
for(let c = 0, x = 1; (++x < 1000); c += Number(!(x % 2) && ([...`${x}`].length === [...`${x}`].filter((x, i, a) => (a.indexOf(x) === i)).length) && (console.log([...`${x}`]) || true))) console.log(c);
```

After executing it, and analyzing its output, I've noticed that there's a pattern hidden in all this:

- From [2, 99], for every 10 unit block, there are scattered number blocks which alternate in length between 4 & 5. Doing $4+5+4+5+4+5+4+5+4+5 = 5(4 + 5) = 45$, checks up when limiting my code to numbers below 100.

  - This is because, for every 10 unit block, half get immediately discarded, and, depending if $10^1$ digit is even or not, another 5 numbers become discarded too, one for every number block left.
- From [100, 999], for every 100 unit block, there appears to happen the same, but now between 40 & 32. $45 + 4(32 + 40) + 40 = 373$, which also checks up with my code.

  - Both same patterns from before get repeated, but second's now «amplified», where for every 100 unit block, half plus five $(5 + 50) = 55$ get immediately discarded.
  - Interestingly enough, for every 40 or 32 unit block, the first pattern of 4 & 5 gets repeated; including the «erased block» into the pattern, it correctly explains the missing 5 or 13 elements that may have got eliminated.

Just to be clear, I ignored numbers with both consecutive -- «220» and non-consecutive -- «202» repeated digits.

Comment: Looks quite Interesting!